# mysqldump 8 client makes empty .sql files with no-create-info

Tags: mysql

I have used commandline `mysqldump` forever to generate data dumps like so:

```
c:\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -uroot -pXYZ -P 3306 --tab=C:\temp\outputdir --no-create-info --skip-triggers  --databases mydb --tables mytbl
```

The purpose of the `tab` option is to create a CSV rather than a file containing SQL insert statements.

The purpose of `--no-create-info` option is to have `mysqldump` generate only a data file, and not also a second `.sql` file containing table creating statements for that table.

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I use version 8.0.15 as the mysqldump client (irrespective of the server version), a second (`.sql`) file is created anyway, though this file is empty.

This command runs perfectly when the mysqldump client is version 5.7.xx

**THE QUESTION:**

Is this a known issue or have I missed something? Again, is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50600 *mysqldump --tab honors --no-data but not --no-create-info*

But it claims versions 5.0+ are affected, which disagrees with your description that this problem didn't exist in 5.7.

Anyway, the bug is still "Verified" which means they have acknowledged it's a bug, but they haven't fixed it.

You can create an account on bugs.mysql.com and click "Affects Me" on that bug page to indicate you would like it to be fixed. The more people who vote for a bug, the more it is noticed by the folks who prioritize the bugs.

Comment: Thank you @Bill for chipping this in. My conclusion would have to be that a regression has now occurred in version 8, since it definitely works correctly in 5.7

Comment: Sure, it's possible they fixed it in 5.7 (or earlier) but never updated the bug I linked to. Then it regressed again. They should have written a test to make sure it didn't regress. You should add a comment to that bug and describe your test case, and the versions affected. And click "Affects Me".